# Breaking long method chains into multiple lines in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm learning Python and pandas and I very often end up with long chains of method calls. I know how to break lists and chains of operators in a way that compiles, but I can't find a way to break method chains in a way that doesn't feel like cheating.

There's plenty of examples of breaking up operator chains and lists in the googles, but I can't find anything decent for method chains.

What would be the best way in Python 3 to break a long chain of method calls into multiple lines?

Say a line like this one:

```
t_values = df_grouped_by_day.sort_values('day_of_week').groupby(['day_of_week', 'day_of_week_name'])['Show_up'].apply(lambda sample: ttest_ind(population, sample)).reset_index()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cheating"? It's either syntactical or it's not... The approach you give in your answer is one perfectly reasonable one, and probably the most readable.

Comment: Wrapping a code block in parentheses just to be able to break it Into multiple lines feels like a not intended use to me, @NathanVērzemnieks . Probably just opinion thing.

Comment: For what it's worth, the approach you show below is what's recommended in [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/): "Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash for line continuation."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Best approach I've came up with so far is this:

```
t_values = (df_grouped_by_day
           .sort_values('day_of_week')
           .groupby(['day_of_week', 'day_of_week_name'])['Show_up']
           .apply(lambda sample: ttest_ind(population, sample))
           .reset_index())
```

Comment: This one is pretty typical. The other option is to use intermediate variables. Both are fine, I think. `pandas` is pretty atypical of Python in that it has a fluent interface.

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, a backslash `\` can be put at the end of line except the last one.

```
t_values = df_grouped_by_day \
           .sort_values('day_of_week') \
           .groupby(['day_of_week', 'day_of_week_name'])['Show_up'] \
           .apply(lambda sample: ttest_ind(population, sample)) \
           .reset_index()
```

Answer (score 4):

For completeness, one more approach is to only break lines within already existing parentheses or bracket pairs. It avoids the parenthesis wrapping and newline-escaping, but I feel it's *much* less readable:

```
t_values = df_grouped_by_day.sort_values('day_of_week'
       ).groupby(['day_of_week', 'day_of_week_name']
       )['Show_up'
       ].apply(lambda sample: ttest_ind(population, sample)
       ).reset_index())
```

Comment: Not an approach I'd use, but the fact that this works gives me more insight about how Python deals with all this.